# My UITableView is nil Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, reload

In my application, every time I run the app I get this error. `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. It is very frustrating. My code for the class:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var whoPaysLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var names:[String] = []
    var amounts:[Int] = []
    var dates:[String] = []
    var whoPays:[String] = []
    var status:[String] = []
    var arrayNumber:Int = -1


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    let textCellIdentifier = "EntityCell"

    var entityCellArray:[String] = []

    let newDate = NSDate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(tableView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func changeWhoPays(sender: UISwitch) {
        if(sender.on){
            whoPaysLabel.text = "\(nameField.text) pays you"
        }else{
            whoPaysLabel.text = "you pay \(nameField.text)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func changeStatus(sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.on{
            statusLabel.text = "paid"
        }else{
            statusLabel.text = "not paid"
        }
    }

    func createNewEntity(){
        names.append(nameField.text)
        var newAmount = self.amountField.text.toInt() ?? 0
        amounts.append(newAmount)
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

        var dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
        dates.append(dateString)
        if whoPaysLabel.text == "\(nameField.text) pays you" || whoPaysLabel.text == "... pays you"{
            whoPays.append("they pay")
        }else{
            whoPays.append("you pay")
        }
        status.append(statusLabel.text!)
        arrayNumber++
        entityCellArray.append("\(names[arrayNumber])  -  \(amounts[arrayNumber])  -  \(dates[arrayNumber])  -  \(status[arrayNumber])")
        let created = UIAlertController(title: "success", message: "creation successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        created.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(created, animated: true, completion: nil)
        nameField.text = ""
        amountField.text = ""
        whoPaysLabel.text = "..."
        datePicker.date = newDate
        println("\(entityCellArray[arrayNumber])")
        printCount()
    }

    //test function, not to be implemented in app
    func printCount(){
       println(entityCellArray.count)
    }

    @IBAction func createButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        createNewEntity()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return entityCellArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = entityCellArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Note: When I hard code my`entityCellArray` with string values and take out `self.tableView.reloadData()`, it works just fine, displaying all of the strings like it is supposed to. Here is a screenshot of my tableView setup with `Main.storyboard`. [image: Note that <code>Info</code>'s class is set to the class with tableView inside it.]

Thank you so much!

Comment: try to change your tableView's outlet's name

Comment: I did, it still produced the nil value error. @iAnurag

Comment: What is printed out by println(tableView)?

Comment: <UITableView: 0x7f9db9051200; frame = (0 28; 320 540); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9db868c070>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9db86880c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 0}> **next line** nil @Jeff

Comment: What does your array contain?

Comment: What I do is get **var names:[String] = []
    var amounts:[Int] = []
    var dates:[String] = []
    var whoPays:[String] = []
    var status:[String] = []** these values from text fields, datePickers, etc. I bind them all (mostly to strings) and then I append them all in one big string into **entityCellArray** and then I reload the table view, which produces the error. @iAnurag

Comment: any specific reason you r reloading table in viewWillappear?

Comment: I saw it on a stack overflow answer. Just wanted to test it out. @iAnurag

Comment: The tableview should load its data itself in your datasource and delegate methods for it. Try println(tableView) again right before you try to reload it, it may not exist yet.

Comment: which line is giving you crash ??

Comment: Your question is misleading, the UITableView is not nil. Please post the full error and what line the app is crashing on.

Comment: UPDATE IMPORTANT!! The line **explicitly** highlighted in that light green shade is **self.tableView.reloadData()** @Jeff

Comment: UPDATE IMPORTANT!! The line explicitly highlighted in that light green shade is self.tableView.reloadData() @anishparajuli

Comment: Add an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint to your debug navigator in Xcode by pressing the + symbol at the bottom and report back.

Comment: tableView  UITableView! nil None is the value of table view @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is crashing on this line

```
cell.textLabel?.text = entityCellArray[indexPath.row]
```

As your `entityCellArray` is array of string so add below line with this
You can prevent the crash from happening by safely unwrapping `cell.textLabel?.text` with.

```
var x = entityCellArray[indexPath.row] as! String
cell.textLabel?.text = x
```

And make sure your array is not empty

Comment: First, a simple but important rule of quality Swift coding, never ever force cast or unwrap anything in Swift. Second, the updated code doesn't change anything that would cause a crash. Third, the only possible crash in the code is if entityCellArray doesn't have enough elements for indexPath.row, and checking for an empty array is incomplete protection from that.

Comment: And bad array index run time errors are different than an unwrapping an optional error.